Packet loss on Single ISP only on Mac
This is the strangest issue I have dealt with. I get about 80%-90% packet loss when pinging some internet services, mostly DNS, next steps would be handy so I don't get brushed off by Verizon's with a simple claim by internet is slow and unresponsive.
High loss rate on my ISP

support.apple.com
8.8.8.8
1.1.1.1

Works Fine on my ISP

apple.com
google.com

I can ping my router, gateway, and IPS DNS without issue but large parts of the internet seem to be dropping. I have Tailscale but have disabled it for the time being to test. I do not think this is a MacBook issue as the sites work fine on a different IPS. I tested at my friend's house, he lives close by less than a mile away but is on a fiber network while I am on Verizon's Wireless.
Example output
This is what I send to get when pinging parts of the internet.
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=249 time=50.718 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=249 time=31.646 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10
Request timeout for icmp_seq 11
Request timeout for icmp_seq 12
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=249 time=34.635 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 14
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=249 time=41.119 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 16
Request timeout for icmp_seq 17
Request timeout for icmp_seq 18
Request timeout for icmp_seq 19
Request timeout for icmp_seq 20
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
22 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 81.8% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 31.646/39.529/50.718/7.311 ms

Computer Info

Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier: Mac15,6
macOS 14.5

Summery
I would really like to get some information on the next steps for troubleshooting this issue as it seems like an ISP problem to me.

Can you group the working and non-working websites by whether you're pinging them over IPv4 or IPv6? I assume you let the OS select whatever is available – do you get the same results when you explicitly specify ping -4 apple.com vs ping -6 apple.com, for example?

What results do you get from a mtr 1.1.1.1 or traceroute 1.1.1.1 (with or without -I, not sure if macOS has that)? That's a slightly suspicious TTL value – some systems do start at 255, but 1.1.1.1 generally doesn't, so it makes me wonder whether the ISP is intercepting access to DNS servers specifically.

I tired ping6. This was the output.
(base) username@firsts-mbp ~ % ping6 support.apple.com
ping6: getaddrinfo -- nodename nor servname provided, or not known I'm going to look into why I'm not able to use ipv6.

That particular site is IPv4-only, but several others in your list are dual-stack. For example, apple.com has both IPv4 and IPv6 available.

I found my AP was not giving out IPv6, I bypassed that and connected to my Gateway's AP directly and it looks like most of the issues I was having are going away. I think the issue is unreliable ipv4 routes causing the timeouts I have been seeing.
